# python argsort indices based on multiple arrays

Tags: python, sorting

I am looking for a function ideally in pure python that is similar to numpy.argsort in that it returns only a list of sorted indices while leaving the original arrays untouched, yet it needs to be able to sort on data contained in multiple arrays.

Example:

```
>>> names = ['xavier', 'bob', 'billy', 'jene', 'samson']
>>> ages = [15, 32, 63, 32, 15]
>>>indexes = sort by ages and then by names
[4, 0, 1, 3, 2]
>>> for i in indexes:
>>>    print "Name", names[i]
>>>    print "Age", ages[i]
```

The sorting function cannot create extra data structures, meaning list comprehension or functions like zip are out of the question. Each array consists of 5 million objects, generating zipped version of the arrays explodes the memory requirements by a factor of at least 3. Using list comprehension such as sorted(..key=lambda x:(names[x],ages[x])) causes a slowdown such as the sort takes over a minute to complete (and the memory requirements to create these intermediary tuples)

So far, as long as I only want to sort on a single array it is fast enough, however since the indices list does not know about the other arrays, I am unable to call multiple "sort" operations as I would if I had a zipped version of the two lists.

Comment: "The sorting function cannot create extra data structures" Impossible to fulfill.

Comment: No intermediary structures like using zip or returning new tuples in a lambda on the key. The problem with those approaches is they duplicate the data. My issue currently is the data structures are around 600MB, if I have to create a zipped version of them, or create a tuple of each of the elements, that causes the memory usage to grow to about 2GB which is not realistic either.

Comment: "they duplicate the data" No they don't. They copy the references.

Comment: `newlist = zip(ages, names)` creates a brand new list, it it is at least making an exact copy of all of the data, not including the overhead of the managing this new list.

Comment: `indexes.sort(key=lambda x:(ages[x],names[x]))` takes minutes to sort.

Comment: `indexes.sort(key=lambda x:names[x])` only takes 10 seconds.

Comment: Gladius: `zip(ages, names)` does create a brand new list, but it does not make an exact copy of all the data, see http://paste.pocoo.org/show/574727/  and note how the reference to the string object containing 'James' is exactly the same.  Now what it -does- do is create N new tuple objects, but these are usually fairly small compared to the data.

Comment: On my local machine, my python process starts with using 400MB RES  after loading in the data. When zip(ages,names) is called, it jumps to 1.1GB RES usage. Those new tuple objects are **very** expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own solution that works great.

Given the following data set:

```
groups = reversed(range(5000000))
ages = [random.randrange(0, 120) for x in groups]
names = ['foobar-%d' % random.randrange(0, 5000) for x in groups]

columns = dict(names=names,ages=ages,groups=groups)

def sort_on(col):
    idxs = range(len(columns[col]))
    idxs.sort(key=lambda x:columns[col][x])
    return idxs
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the best I can think. Most `int`s in python are singleton so the new list created by the first `sorted` call should not create much more brand new objects. The second `sorted` call should create a smaller list, it depends on how much different the ages are.

```
>>> import itertools, operator
>>> names = ['xavier', 'bob', 'billy', 'jene', 'samson']
>>> ages = [15, 32, 63, 32, 15]
>>> itemgetter = operator.itemgetter(1)
>>> sortedAges = sorted(enumerate(ages), key=itemgetter)
>>> for k, group in itertools.groupby(sortedAges, itemgetter):
...     g = sorted([(i, names[i]) for i, _ in group], key=itemgetter)
...     for i, name in g:
...         print 'Name:', name, 'Age:', ages[i]
... 
Name: samson Age: 15
Name: xavier Age: 15
Name: bob Age: 32
Name: jene Age: 32
Name: billy Age: 63
```